# Difference Between [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init] and [CAShapeLayer layer]

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, graphics, core-graphics

I noticed that most people, when initializing a `CAShapeLayer` use:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
```

Rather than using the initializer:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
```

I'm wondering is there any particular difference in using either one of these, or which one is usually better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one returns an autoreleased object. Since it's been autoreleased, you aren't an owner of it. The object will get released automatically for you, when the autorelease pool (in which it resides) gets released.

The second one returns an object with +1 retain count. You are an owner of that object and hence are responsible to `release` it. However - With ARC you may not need to call `release` as it does for us.

Related Links:

1. [Objective C Method Families](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#family)
2. [Basic Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH)

Comment: Thanks, I'm already aware of the memory management effects, but not understanding why with CALayers people use [CALayer layer] instead of allocating a new object. Is it for caching purposes?

Comment: With Manual memory Management: Since the first approach returns autorelease object, which will be automatically released, we typically do that inside individual method implementation. This is so because we don't need to then call `release` on it. Whereas if you do alloc+init, you need to release it, right? Else you will be leaking memory as you created object and didn't release it. However, with ARC it wouldn't matter much.

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider. I think you're misunderstanding what [CALayer layer] does. It does alloc/init a new object -- the only difference is the memory management effect.

Comment: With ARC, there is no practical difference, as ARC handles all of the memory-management obligations that you previously had to worry about. Whichever way you create the layer, you *will not* need to send `release` or `autorelease` to it under ARC. Not only that, but you couldn't even if you wanted to—both messages are illegal under ARC.